# Safari on iOS won't load a page on my WordPress, only toplevel domain

Tags: ios, safari, url, wordpress

I'm trying to text someone a page on my website. When I tested it the url in the text message was changed from http://www.example.com/test to http://www.example.com/ , the end of the url being stripped off. When I manually enter http://www.example.com/test into iOS Safari the same thing happens, it loads http://www.example.com, stripping the /test from the url. My site is built in WordPress, and the page loads fine in both firefox and chrome on both my MacBook and Linux Desktop. In Macbook Safari I re-entered the url after visiting the site and was able to load the page.

For some reason it won't go to the permalink for a specific page

Comment: What address is displayed in Safari when you tap the address bar? - I.e. it is standard that Safari only shows the domain - but when you tap it, you should see the full address - including path.

Comment: It defaults to removing everything after the domain. then when I add /test or /test/ to the url it gets removed again. In iOS I managed to get it to load by entering it manually after the website had loaded to the domain itself, but iMessage still stripping everything after .com from the URL.

When I click the address bar after trying to load the url for the first time and the problem I mentioned occurs it doesn't have /test/ on the end or anything after .com